# How to set Rails cache in rspec controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to set Rails.cache in rspec controller test, however the cache is always blank inside the controller method. What is approach to do this?

**User Model**

```
def user_token
 Rails.cache.fetch(id) 
end
```

**User Controller**

```
 if current_user.user_token
      @user = @account.users.find(params[:id])
      @user.revoke_seat(:admin, current_user)
      render :template => "/admin/users/revoke_seat"
    else
      render :js => "window.location.href='#{server_url}/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=#{client_id}&state=#{request.referrer}?auto_revoke_seat=true&redirect_uri=#{auth_service_callback_url}";
    end
```

**Rspec**

```
 before do
    users(:admin).stub(:internal_admin?).and_return(true)
    login_as :admin
    Rails.cache.write(user.id, "testToken", expires_in: 2.minutes)
  end

  it "should redirect to authentication service to generate access token" do
      expect(user).to receive(:user_token).and_return(true)
      xhr :put, :revoke_seat, account_id: account.id, id: user.id
      expect(response).to render_template('admin/users/revoke_seat')
      expect(assigns(:account)).to eq(account)
      expect(assigns(:user)).to eq(user)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the before method as:

```
before do
   users(:admin).stub(:internal_admin?).and_return(true)
   login_as :admin
   allow(Rails.cache).to receive(:fetch).with(user.id).and_return("testToken")
end
```